# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: java, android, ssl, server

I have an Android App that calls an API hosted on my server. Everything was working fine for months. But today, the Android App is failing to connect to the server and it's showing this stacktrace:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
                                                                                 at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:361)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:121)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:100)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                                 at com.xxx.xxx.data.APIService$Factory$1.intercept(APIService.java:37)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
                                                                                 at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
                                                                                 at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                                                                 at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:144)
                                                                                 at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:125)
```

I ran the following openssl command:

```
openssl s_client -connect XXX.com:443 -servername XXX.com -showcerts | openssl x509 -text -noout
depth=0 CN = XXX
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = XXX
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
```

It is then followed by showing infos about a Certificate.

The App uses Retrofit to connect to the Server. The server is hosted on Bluehost. I have the SSL certificate enabled.

Is there a quick workable solution that I can do? And why has this suddenly started to happen? Is there a fix from the Server side so that I need to release an update for the App?

Comment: Google how to ignore that exception, this is not the most secure but fastest solution. If you want real help show us what openssl s_client tells you about the certificate used

Comment: are u using https or http?

Comment: @Marged Thank you for your comment. Check my edit, I ran the openssl and posted the first few lines. BlueHost offers a Free SSL certificate by just enabling it in the settings. What do I need to do now?

Comment: @Anurag Thank you for your comment. I am and always have been using https.